# Create an AWS volume/snapshot from a tarball

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a large tarball (expands to 13G of stuff). I want an EBS snapshot of a volume with the contents of the tarball as the contents of the volume.

I have an existing rig that involves using Linux loopback mounts to create an ext2 file system, fill it up, unmount it, push it to S3, and tell Amazon to make a snapshot from it. I don't like this rig, because it can only be run on servers where I've set up the apparatus -- but mostly because I suspect that I've reinvented a wheel.

Is there a common technique that makes more use of Amazon tools? I'm imagining something like a chef recipe that creates an instance with the necessary big empty volume, pushes the content to S3, pulls it from S3 to the instance and unpacks it.

Answer (score 0):

Packer from Hashicorp is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Sure, if it worked. I could never get it to function, and the support environment was a ghost town.